# pymysql 2- applicaions SELECT INSERT Query

Tags: mysql, database, select, insert, pymysql

Application 1 keeps connection open and selects data from database. I need to keep this connection open for my application. Application 2 inserts the data into the database. Application one is only able to see the data that was in the DB at the time of the connection. Even with a new Select Query the data is not up to date. You can see the output below where I started application 2 which started inserting data. When I started application one, up to 5 was already inserted into the DB. Application 2 went on and continued to add new rows up to 9, but Application 1 cannot see the new rows UNLESS I close the connection and re-open it. I am working with very high speeds and the connection time kills my application. I need to be able to leave the connection open the entire time.

#Applicaion 1

```
import pymysql
import time as t

queryconn = pymysql.connect(host='x, user='x', passwd='x',
                             db='TestDB')

while True:
        queryconncurser = queryconn.cursor()
        # query database
        queryconncurser.execute(f"SELECT * FROM `testQuerys`")
        items = queryconncurser.fetchall()
        print(items)

        t.sleep(4)
```

output:

```
(2,), (3,), (4,), (5,)
(2,), (3,), (4,), (5,)
(2,), (3,), (4,), (5,)
(2,), (3,), (4,), (5,)
(2,), (3,), (4,), (5,)
```

#Application 2

```
import pymysql
import time as t

n = 1
while True:
    queryconn =  pymysql.connect(host='x', user='x', passwd='x', db='TestDB')
    queryconncurser = queryconn.cursor()
    n = n + 1
    # query database
    queryconncurser.execute(f"INSERT INTO testQuerys (testData)  VALUES ({n}) ")
    queryconn.commit()
    print(n)
    t.sleep(4)
    queryconn.close()
```

Output:

```
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

Comment: have you tried this with mysql connctor?

Comment: What happens if application 1 calls `querycursor.commit()`?

Comment: I added a commit to the SELECT and it works! I guess InnoDB uses a snapshot for the Query. The snapshot is refreshed when you open the new connection or add the commit. Thank you!!!!